# Using Rational Team Concert for requirement and test management

Tags: rtc, rational-team-concert

We are a small team and we need an ALM solution for our ongoing development. We heard that RTC can provide a basic requirement management, test plans and test execution management (besides source control and change management).

Do you think it's really capable of providing them all? In particular, we need the following, as well as be able to link them all:

- Requirements
- Test plans
- Features
- Document bugs and test results

Saying again, we're a small team. We do not need rich tools for requirements (such as RRC or DOORS) nor test management tools such as RQM or HP-QC. We'd like to know if RTC itself can provide all these needs for basic usage.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize RTC in order to:

- define specific [work item](https://jazz.net/library/article/42/) (that you can call "requirements", or "test", or "feature")
- define one or several timelines, with their own set of iterations ([an iteration](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.concert.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_practice_planning_iteration.html) equals a start date and an end date), for planning purpose

So yes, you can do that as long as:

- you don't expect *all* the features of a dedicated requirement tool (Doors).
- you understand those concepts ("requirements", "tests", ...) aren't there out of the box, and need to be defined.

Comment: Thank you. How much time do you think is necessary to customize/define ("requirements", "tests", ...)? Do you mean a few hours, a few days or even a few weeks?

Comment: @user986086 few hours to a few days at most, provided you don't try to emulate all the features of a requirement management tool or a fancy planning report format.